# Why is finite-ness so important in proofs?

Tags: logic, soft-question, proof-theory

Oftentimes I notice that in proof-writing, something that both my professors and textbook-writers stress is that such-and-such procedure must terminate. Other times, if we want to verify a property is true for some set, they will mention that there are only finitely many elements to check, which apparently makes our job easier. My question is why it is that finiteness is nicer than non-finiteness. I get that in an infinite set, we will never be able to finish checking "everything", but why does that matter? It's not like we're describing a process that a person will have to go through and actually do. I would imagine that it's a logic thing, but I haven't studied enough logic to understand it.

Comment: Because you can (theoretically) perform a proof by exhaustion if it is finite...

Comment: This is pretty vague.  For things like proofs by infinite descent, the point is that the process has to terminate because there is an absolute lower bound.  Otherwise, of course there are times when one can check all of a finite number of cases.  But it would help a lot if you gave an example of what was puzzling you.

Comment: @lulu sure, here's the problem that got me thinking about it in the first place: if $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then $dim(W) \le dim(V)$. "If $W$ is not the zero space, then there exists a nonzero $x_1$ in W. Thus the set $\{x_1\}$ is independent. Keep choosing vectors $x_2, ... x_k$, if possible, such that $\{x_1, ..., x_k\}$ is independent. Since no independent subset of $V$ can contain more than $n$ vectors, this process must stop a stage where $k \le n$. Then adding any new vector would make the set dependent. So $\{x_1, ... x_k\}$ generates $W$, and is a basis for it. So $dim(W) \le dim(V)$

Comment: That just seems like an awkward phrasing of an obvious point.  If $V$ has dimension $n$ then you can't have $n+1$ independent vectors in $W$, since those would also be independent vectors in $V$.  That's all.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But is there any problem with saying "choose vectors so that $\{x_1, ..., x_k\}$ is independent"? If we only had finitely many vectors to choose from, we could say "go through all the vectors and use the test for dependence". But if $W$ is infinite, does this produce any difficulty? Because I would think it's impossible to check every finite linear combination of vectors, if the vectors are from an infinite set.

Comment: Well, it is certainly true that in infinite dimensional vector spaces, notions of basis and such take on an Axiom of Choice sort of character.  But that has no obvious connection to the problem you posed in your post.   For finite dimensional vector spaces...no serious issues should arise.

Comment: Maybe it would help you to think of your vector space argument as being a proof by contradiction.  If, contrary to wishes, $\dim W>\dim V=n$, then (by definition) there would exist a collection of  $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in $W$.  But then those would also be linearly independent vectors in $V$, in contradiction of the assumption that $\dim V= n$.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: If the proof of statement $S$ does not terminate, on what ground can we assert that the statement $S$ has been proved ?

Comment: But IMO your a conflating "finite proof" with "proof about a finite set/process". The proof that there are infinite many prime number is *finite*, i.e. it is a finite "linguistic object".

Answer (score 2):

The more explicit the proof, the clearer image we have of the objects involved in it.

For example, if you want to prove that a function $T\colon X\to Y$ extends to a function from some larger $X'$ with certain properties, having a complete description of the extension is better than having used an abstract theorem to prove the existence of the extension.

Finite sets are great this way, because of their finiteness they are easy to deal with by recursion: when you remove an element of a finite set, it becomes strictly smaller. Not so for infinite sets in general.

Proofs are also finite, which makes sense, since proofs are something we want to think of as objects we could possibly write on a piece of paper. When we have to make finitely many steps, even if we are using somehow abstract logical rules, we can still think of them as being somewhat descriptive.

For example, suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are non-empty sets. Then there is a function $f$ such that $f(i)\in X_i$. The easy way to prove this is to repeat the existential instantiation rule: $X_1$ is not empty, i.e. $\exists x(x\in X_1)$, so we can add a new symbol $x_1$ and declare $x_1\in X_1$. Rinse and repeat until $x_n$ is given, and define $f(i)=x_i$.

If the family of sets is infinite we can no longer do this. In that case we need to use the axiom of choice we simply asserts the existence of $f$. But we have no idea what this $f$ might be. And while the existential instantiation is somehow abstract and mysterious, we can at least grasp it conceptually as an iterative process, compared to the use of the axiom of choice which just instantly creates this function.

Comment: Nice answer. I suppose it shows that the OP's question is contingent on what kind of infinite set they're talking about, i.e., whether it (and the proof in question) can be associated to a choice function or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a rather vague question, but here is a very nice (and useful) property of finite sets.

> Let $E$ be a finite set and let $f:E \to E$ be a function. Then  the
>   following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is injective,
> 2. $f$ is surjective,
> 3. $f$ is bijective.